# How to configuration sssd for sftp logins in kubernetes pod level

Tags: sftp, ldap

1. I have deployed SFTP service in kuberenetes pod level through statefulset.
2. I want to authenticate SFTP login users through LDAP, hence I configured sssd service to configure a ldap client on SFTP machine.Used SSL certificates.
3. But authentication is not happening when I am testing through winscp. “Access denied” even credentials correct.